# C - explicit memory reclamation

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic

I have a number of data structures (trees, queues, lists), created using dynamic allocation routines (malloc, calloc). Under some critical conditions, the program should terminate. Traversing all objects to free their memory takes long time.

Is it safe to avoid traversing all data structures just before program stops? If yes, does it apply to all operating systems and environments (e.g. multiple threads)?

Comment: Technically speaking, `free()`ing or not memory doesn't make any difference to the OS and to the other programs, so you could not `free()` at all.

Comment: Im curious is it not good practice to release all the memory that you dynamically allocated? Also by not releasing the memory you allocated could that potentially lead to memory leaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the memory dynamically allocated by a process is released back to the OS on process termination, doesn't matter intentionally or via a crash. Same happens with files and sockets - ref counts inside the kernel get decremented and resources get released if there are no more references.

An exception to the above might be the shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

When a program (i.e., a process) terminates, all local and heap memories are automatically reclaimed. Note that these memory regions are specific to a process. So, you may skip the traverse and deallocation just before the program termination. However, if the program uses a shared/global memory, then you need to explicitly reclaim that. Finally, it applies, at least, Linux/Unix and Windows. I believe it applies to all modern operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. In any modern OS, memory is private to each *process*, and once the process exits, all memory is reclaimed by the OS (unless the OS itself is broken).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `free()` all your dynamically-allocated memory before terminating the program.  The operating system releases all the memory that was owned by the process anyway.  It also closes any network connections that you had open.